# NPM Dependency Resolution Conflicts

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

When I run `node install` I get the following output:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: google-map-react@2.1.10
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.3" from @deck.gl/react@8.7.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/@deck.gl/react
npm ERR!     @deck.gl/react@"8.7.8" from deck.gl@8.7.8
npm ERR!     node_modules/deck.gl
npm ERR!       deck.gl@"^8.7.8" from the root project
npm ERR!   15 more (@emotion/react, @emotion/styled, @mui/base, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from google-map-react@2.1.10
npm ERR! node_modules/google-map-react
npm ERR!   google-map-react@"^2.1.10" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from google-map-react@2.1.10
npm ERR!   node_modules/google-map-react
npm ERR!     google-map-react@"^2.1.10" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

and here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "frontend",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.6.2",
        "@mui/material": "^5.6.3",
        "deck.gl": "^8.7.8",
        "react": "^18.1.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
        "react-router": "^6.3.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried already `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` and `npm install --force` none of which changed the error message. I also tried `npm install --legacy-peer-deps --save google-maps-react` to see if I had to perform this individually for each package, no luck. I am aware that this error is relatively common, and it has something to do with the npm version and the **dreaded breaking changes**.

Does anyone know any other steps I can take?

Comment: Try to check your node version and it's compatibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by running `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` after going from my pc's version of node 18.0.0 to the latest 16 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0"

1. npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
2. npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps
3. npm install  --force

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by running the below instructions.

> `npm config set legacy-peer-deps true`

This command sets the `legacy-peer-deps` configuration option to true. This means that any legacy peer dependencies that are defined in the package.json file will be installed when you run the NPM install command.

> `npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps`

This command installs the dependencies defined in the package.json file, including any legacy peer dependencies that are defined. The --save option tells NPM to add the installed dependencies to the dependencies section in the package.json file.

> `npm install --force`

This command forces NPM to reinstall all the dependencies defined in the package.json file, even if they are already installed. The `--force` option can be useful if you have made changes to the package.json file and need to reinstall the dependencies to reflect those changes.